# jQuery JSON returned from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a simple `HTML form` where user can search a word from database and `PHP` return result as a `JSON` object if the word is in database.

Strange thing is that a `JSON` object is returned for a word that is in database when user searches by clicking on a button instead of pressing enter key. I have the following two functions to deal with either when user press enter key or click on the button to search. How to improve my code to get the `JSON` object from `PHP` when user searches by pressing enter key after they have typed the word in text field?

```
$('#word-submit').on('click', function() {
  var word = $('#word').val();
  $.post('ajax/name.php', {word: word}, function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(obj); //I see the object in Chrome console log.
  });

});

$('#word').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var word = $('#word').val();
    $.post('ajax/name.php', {word: word}, function(data) {
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(obj); //No object is return here. Why? May be something is wrong in my code.
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="word">
      <input type="button" id="word-submit" value="Search">

    </form>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP script works just fine. So I am not pasting it here.

Comment: Look like there is nothing wrong with code, when you pressing enter, did't the browser refresh??

Comment: Yeah. The page gets reload when I press enter, but not when I click on the button. It just simply fetches the result and display it without reloading the page.

Comment: can you put `e.preventDefault();` inside if block after first bracket, and try to enter again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your form is submitting. I would just add one listener on the form's *submit* event which should handle clicking the button and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, eg

```
$(form).on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit
    var word = $('#word').val();
    $.post('ajax/name.php', {word: word}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, 'json');
});
```

Ideally, you shouldn't have to parse the JSON or even tell jQuery the response data type (see `'json'` arg above). Make sure your PHP script has something like this...

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($someDataArrayOrObject);
exit;
```

---

In order to make the button work with the above, change its type to `submit`, ie

```
<input type="submit" id="word-submit" value="Search">
```

Comment: @Zip you're welcome. I had to add one more point about the button type  so hopefully you didn't miss that

Answer (score 0):

button work because it prevent the form auto submit / reload it self.

pressing enter key on that textbox causing the form to submit and then reload it self without even triggering the `$('#word').keypress(function(e))`.

Comment: the question was about why pushing enter in the textbox doing nothing while pushing the button work.
i miss read the type submit due to it's name id has submit in it :) sorry for that.